# Increase the github xrate limit in R

Tags: r, github, github-api

Increasing xrate limit related to github api in R, I am using rgithub package in R to extract the pull requests from github. I have registered the application and generated the client id's. The code of using xrate limit in R, the ctx contains the details clientids. To increase the xrate limit I am running the curl command with details. Is this the correct way to increase the rate-limit. Please suggest any other way possible

```
      ctx = interactive.login("clientid", "client_secret_id")

      owner = "a"
      repo = "repo_name"

      comments <- function(i){
      commits <- get.issue.comments(owner = owner, repo = repo, number = i, 
      ctx = get.github.context(), per_page=100)
      links <- digest_header_links(commits)
      number_of_pages <- links[2,]$page
      if (number_of_pages != 0)
     try_default(for (n in 1:number_of_pages){
       if (as.integer(commits$headers$`x-ratelimit-remaining`) < 5)
        Sys.sleep(as.integer(commits$headers$`x-ratelimit-reset`)
        - as.POSIXct(Sys.time()) %>% as.integer())
      else
    get.issue.comments(owner = owner, repo = repo, number = i, 
    ctx =get.github.context(), per_page=100, page = n)
       }, default = NULL)
     else 
    return(commits)
    }
   list <- c(issueid) # a issue id in github
   comments_lists <- lapply(list, comments)
    curl -i 'https://api.github.com/users/whatever?client_id=&client_secret=yyyy'
```

Comment: That's the curl code. What did you try in R? And are you doing it from scratch?  There are clients out there to interact with github

Comment: I am Sorry for not being clear, I haven't used the command in R. I am using rgithub package in R. I have registered the application in github and generated the client ids. So I am running the curl command  with the clientid's to increase the xratelimit for the application and thats not happening. Is there any other way to get the full authorization